# Number of ways to play $n$ games without losing three in a row

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

So I'm trying to solve this problem but I'm having a few difficulties.

> A gambler decides to play successive games of blackjack until he loses three times in a row. (Thus the gambler could play five games by losing the first, winning the second, and losing the final three or by winning the first two and losing the final three.)
>
> These possibilities can be symbolized as LWLLL and WWLLL. Let $g_n$ be the number of ways the gambler can play $n$ games. Explain your answer as well.
>
> a. Find $g_3$, $g_4$, and $g_5$.
> b. Find $g_{10}$.

When it's asking for $g_3$ for example, Am I supposed to come up with $3$ scenarios in which the win/lose events could happen?

Comment: What does the problem statement say $g_n$ is?  So what is $g_3$?

Comment: @Paul Plummer Gn, is the number of ways the gambler can play n games. So is g3 the number of ways the gambler can play 3 games?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: @user214301not play. The number of ways the gambler can loose the game.

Answer (score 2):

Presumably $g_n$ is the number of sequences of L and W ending in LLL in which the first time that three L's appear consecutively are at the end. So $g_3 = 1$ since the only such sequence is LLL, $g_4 = 1$ since the only such sequence is WLLL, and $g_5 = 2$ as you mention.

More generally, let $a_n,b_n,c_n$ be the number of sequences in which there are no three consecutive LLL's which end (respectively) in 0,1,2 consecutive L's. We have $g_n = a_{n-3}$ and
$$
\begin{align*}
a_0 &= 1 \\
b_0 &= 0 \\
c_0 &= 0 \\
a_{n+1} &= a_n+b_n+c_n \\
b_{n+1} &= a_n \\
c_{n+1} &= b_n
\end{align*}
$$
We can reduce it to a more usual recurrence relation using $b_n = a_{n-1}$ and $c_n = b_{n-1} = a_{n-2}$. This shows that
$$
a_{n+1} = a_n + a_{n-1} + a_{n-2}, \quad a_0 = 1, \quad a_1 = 1, \quad a_2 = 2. 
$$
In terms of $g_n$, we get
$$
g_{n+1} = g_n + g_{n-1} + g_{n-2}, \quad g_3 = 1, \quad g_4 = 1, \quad g_5 = 2. 
$$
The first few values are
$$ 1,1,2,4,7,13,24,44,81,\ldots. $$
In particular, $g_{10} = 44$.
The asymptotic growth rate of $g_n$ is $g_n = \Theta(\gamma^n)$, where $\gamma \approx1.84$ is the unique real root of the cubic $t^3-t^2-t-1$.

If instead of having a length-three losing streak you consider a length-two losing streak, you get the Fibonacci numbers (with an appropriate shift), try it!

Answer (score 0):

Using a *recurrence relation* seems like the natural choice here:

- Let $a_n$ denote the number of combinations of length $n$ that start with $0$ Ls
- Let $b_n$ denote the number of combinations of length $n$ that start with $1$ L
- Let $c_n$ denote the number of combinations of length $n$ that start with $2$ Ls

Then:

- $a_6=2$ `(WLWLLL, WWWLLL)`
- $b_6=1$ `(LWWLLL)`
- $c_6=1$ `(LLWLLL)`
- $a_{n+1}=a_n+b_n+c_n$ `(add W at the beginning of every combination)`
- $b_{n+1}=a_n        $ `(add L at the beginning of every combination)`
- $c_{n+1}=b_n        $ `(add L at the beginning of every combination)`

Finally, let $g_n$ denote the number of combinations of length $n$, hence $g_n=a_n+b_n+c_n$.

---

For $n<6$, you need to calculate $g_n$ "manually":

- $g_3=1$ `(LLL)`
- $g_4=1$ `(WLLL)`
- $g_5=2$ `(LWLLL, WWLLL)`

Let's calculate $g_{10}$:

```
  n  |  a  |  b  |  c  |  g
-----|-----|-----|-----|-----
  6  |  2  |  1  |  1  |  4
-----|-----|-----|-----|-----
  7  |  4  |  2  |  1  |  7
-----|-----|-----|-----|-----
  8  |  7  |  4  |  2  | 13
-----|-----|-----|-----|-----
  9  | 13  |  7  |  4  | 24
-----|-----|-----|-----|-----
 10  | 24  | 13  |  7  | 44
```